# Are there any drawbacks to eliminating the defaultstore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am refactoring my code to eliminate the default store and use ES6+ defaults as follows:

That is I am moving defaults from an object passed in as follows:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, defaultstore, middleware);
```

to directly into the reducers.  This way I can locate them easier.  The two methods are shown below ...

**defaultstore**

```
  Menu: {
    current: 'Articles'
  },
```

**reducer function**

```
// People is the default
const Menu = (state = {current: 'People'}, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'updateMenu':
    newState.current = action.current;
    return newState;
  }
  return state;
};
```

Is there any reason not to do this.  It makes the code more readable.